# How to update Julia in ssh clusters

Tags: linux, ssh, julia, cluster-computing, openssh

I'm working as a PhD student in a lab with ssh clusters, I have the access to connect to each one of them (there's no queue system, as it is a small lab, hence, as long as someone is not using a lot of cores in each computer I can run my programs on them).

Currently the lab doesn't have a cluster administrator so its maintenance is in the hands of two researchers with computer knowledge. Currently, the clusters have a very old version of Julia (0.5.1) and I need an update in order to work; however, one of the two researchers in charge told me that it will require a very large amount of time and stopping all current process in order to update Julia, so he is unwilling to make the update on the clusters.

Is there a way that I can update the Julia version on the clusters all by myself? Without interrupting nor canceling any of the current processes?

I believe non of the current processes are being run with Julia, as I am the only one in the lab who works with it. The languages being used for these processes are C, C++ and Fortran.

Comment: This link was posted on the Julia Slack for a somewhat similar question (updating packages on secure systems), so it might be helpful: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/installing-packages-via-an-ssh-socks-proxy-on-a-compute-cluster/71735

Comment: If you can login and run code, you should be able to install your own version of julia that you can update as you please just like you would do on your own machine, but depending on internet access from the remote machine you might have to get fancy (as @AshlinHarris linked to above). I am also a PhD student and this is what I do on my school's computing resources as they are often several releases behind (although not as far behind as 0.5.1!). If you haven't done something like that before and want some help happy to chat.

Answer (score 2):

Julia does not need to be installed system-wide to be used. In fact on all OSes - Linux, Mac and Windows - the Julia distribution is portable and self-contained.

So, the easiest way to get this is to use [`juliaup`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/juliaup) to install julia on all the nodes, and use it to manage all the julia versions you need.